# Rewrite htaccess URL base for multiple GET variables with PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, get, url-rewriting

I am looking to create a PHP file that can handle multiple GET variables and output data accordingly, however I would like to remove the base "category" URL element in order to shorten it, with htaccess, like so:

```
http://website.com/news/politics
http://website.com/videos/funny
http://website.com/posts/food
```

Currently I use different files for each type, but it is a pain:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/?$ tpl-news.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^videos/([^/]+)/?$ tpl-videos.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]+)/?$ tpl-posts.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
etc ...
```

Alternatively, I could use the following:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ tpl-category.php?type=$1&slug=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

I do not want to have a URL like:

```
http://website.com/category/news/politics
http://website.com/category/videos/funny
http://website.com/category/posts/food
```

But would like to remove the "category" from the URL like so:

```
http://website.com/news/politics
http://website.com/videos/funny
http://website.com/posts/food
```

However other pages / URLs, for example like the ones below, should not be affected by this rule:

```
http://website.com/account/user
http://website.com/newspost/abcdef // a single post page
http://website.com/videopost/abcdef // a single video page
```

These "types" (news, videos, posts, ...) are limited in number, i.e. I have no objection predefining those, so that they do not conflict with other URLs of the page (such as image folders, admin sections, user profile sub pages, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this generic rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(news|videos|post)/([^/]+)/?$ tpl-category.php?type=$1&slug=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Or if you want to use existing `.php` files e.g. `tpl-news.php`, `tpl-post.php` etc then use:

```
RewriteRule ^(news|videos|post)/([^/]+)/?$ tpl-$1.php?slug=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you @anubhava, it does work for the category pages, however now some other URLs are messed up with that rule. I added some more specifications above, see edits towards the bottom.